# Is it possible to enhance the rake test task and merge test results together?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rake, testunit

I am writing tests for my sidekiq workers and I want them to run when I type "rake" in the terminal. I have that working - I added the following to my Rakefile:

```
namespace :test do
  Rake::TestTask.new(:workers) do |t|
    t.libs << "test"
    t.pattern = 'test/workers/**/*_test.rb'
  end
end

Rake::Task[:test].enhance ["test:workers"]
```

When I run rake I get something like this as my output:

```
Run options: --seed 51172

# Running tests:

SS

Finished tests in 0.005594s, 357.5259 tests/s, 0.0000 assertions/s.

2 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 2 skips
Run options: --seed 17561

# Running tests:

S............................................SSSS..SSSSS......

Finished tests in 2.037526s, 30.4291 tests/s, 45.6436 assertions/s.

62 tests, 93 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 10 skips
```

The S characters are skips - I haven't finished all of my tests yet. So my question is basically - is there a way to merge the two sets of tests after enhancing? Should I be doing something different than an enhance?

If I'm doing anything blatantly wrong please let me know, and thanks for reading this. And just in case it is needed: Rails 4 w/ Ruby 2.0

Answer (score 1):

Try this, change the following:

```
Rake::TestTask.new(:workers) do |t|
```

to this:

```
Rails::TestTask.new(:workers) do |t|
```

It's a small change, but fixes the problem for me. It means your entire test suite will run with merged output.

Comment: This may or may not work but sadly I can't confirm with the same codebase since it was asked a long time ago. I'll try it on my next project though - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

there is a simple workaround for this:

```
bundle exec rake test:all
```

if you want to see how rails tasks are created look [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/eff8196190c0c4a36f17fe5519ed5158edf5db59/railties/lib/rails/test_unit/testing.rake)